# Automatically update data every hour

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

I'm trying to understand how EVENTs work.  Can someone explain the concept, preferably with a demo?

I think this would update data every hour; am I correct?

```
CREATE EVENT reset
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 HOUR
        DO
update T1 
set state=1 
where time < date_sub(now(),interval 24 hour) 
  and (state=0 or state=2) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to think of events is like a [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) in Unix, which can be used to automate recurring tasks - e.g. updating and/or purging records from a large table at 03:00 every morning.

I'm going to assume that you're running MySQL.

The first thing you do is turn on the event scheduler process as follows:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

or better yet, put `event_scheduler = ON` into the `[mysqld]` section of your my.cnf (or my.ini).

The general syntax is:

```
CREATE EVENT `event_name` 
ON SCHEDULE schedule
[ON COMPLETION [NOT] PRESERVE] 
[ENABLE | DISABLE | DISABLE ON SLAVE]
DO BEGIN
    -- event body
END;
```

The schedule part can be

- Run once on a specific date/time:
  AT ‘YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM.SS’
  e.g. AT ‘2011-06-01 02:00.00’
- Run once after a specific period has elapsed:
  AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL n [HOUR|MONTH|WEEK|DAY|MINUTE]
  e.g. AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY
- Run at specific intervals forever:
  EVERY n [HOUR|MONTH|WEEK|DAY|MINUTE]
  e.g. EVERY 1 DAY
- Run at specific intervals during a specific period:
  EVERY n [HOUR|MONTH|WEEK|DAY|MINUTE] STARTS date ENDS date
  e.g. EVERY 1 DAY STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 WEEK ENDS ‘2012-01-01 00:00.00’

An example would be:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE 
    EVENT `archive_blogs` 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK STARTS '2011-07-24 03:00:00' 
    DO BEGIN

        -- copy deleted posts
        INSERT INTO blog_archive (id, title, content) 
        SELECT id, title, content
        FROM blog
        WHERE deleted = 1;

        -- copy associated audit records
        INSERT INTO audit_archive (id, blog_id, changetype, changetime) 
        SELECT audit.id, audit.blog_id, audit.changetype, audit.changetime 
        FROM audit
        JOIN blog ON audit.blog_id = blog.id
        WHERE blog.deleted = 1;

        -- remove deleted blogs and audit entries
        DELETE FROM blog WHERE deleted = 1;

    END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Here, a blog table is purged and an audit table updated at 03:00 every Sunday.

Most of the material above was taken from [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/) and [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/). And, of course, it is also worthwhile looking at your server's documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html) (check version - but it hasn't changed much in a while!).

Events are a very handy item to have in your DBA toolkit - I would urge anyone to make full use of them - no more forgotten updates or other (repetetive, monotonous) tasks.

Of course, this functionality can be used in conjuntion with `cron` - i.e. you might, after your purge and update at 03:00, then use `cron` to kick off mysqldump to take a backup of your database (not much point in backing it up **before**!

Comment: *The first thing you do is turn on the event scheduler process as follows* I think it's the last thing one is to do. And the first thing one is not to forget to do...

Comment: And one more difference between `event sheduler` and `cron` - `crontab` is statiс file externally modified just as event expired is immediately auto-dropped if `ON COMPLETION PRESERVE` is not specified.

Comment: Yeah, OK, fair enough - create your event first and then activate it... de minimis non curat Vérace! :-) It is easy enough though, to create your event and then to clean prevent to activate the event scheduler - it's happened to (err...) people I (umm...) might have (ah...) known, in the (uhhh...) past...

Comment: My reading of the docco is that the event is only dropped if it can't apply in a future date - i.e. if you've scheduled it for every Sunday - it won't auto-drop. But, if you've only scheduled it for, say, 2018, it will auto-drop on its last run in 2018.

Comment: If event can apply in a future date - it is not expired.